# Ubuntu 23.10 connected to wifi but no internet

Tags: wireless, 23.10, rtl8192ce

I just install Ubuntu 23.10, connect to my wifi and there are no internet, only "question mark" on wifi icon

Comment: The questionmark on the wifi icon means that a known Wifi network is detected but no connection is established. Did you enter the right credentials to connect to the network?

Comment: It's also possible the the access point and/or router needs to be rebooted.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Hawing the same problem on ThinkPad T440p. It's connected, have IP address but can't ping even a router.